# Sum digits in an integer

Tags: java, variables

I am new to Java, and I am working to sum an integer's individual numbers. I believe that my problem lies in the formula I am using to obtain the values of the individual numbers, but I am hoping to gain some insight from the brilliant people here! Please note that this code works in the test cases I have used with one exception: the integer 234. This is returning a result of 10 for the sum.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise2_6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter an integer between 0 and 1000: ");

        int x = input.nextInt();
        int firstNum = x / 100;
        int secondNum = x % 10;
        int thirdNum = secondNum  % 10;
        int fourthNumber = x / 10;
        int sum = firstNum + secondNum + thirdNum;

        System.out.println("The sum of all digits in " + x +" is " + sum);



    }}
```

Comment: use a debugger. Or pencil and paper

Comment: Have you tried to do the calculation by hand for 234 to see where your algo is wrong?

Comment: And/or try printing out the intermediate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is

```
int thirdNum = secondNum  % 10;
```

Since `secondNum` is already between 0 and 9, this will just make `thirdNum` the same as `secondNum`.

I suspect you wanted

```
int secondNum = x % 100 / 10;
int thirdNum = x % 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are assigning the value to int, the calculation will be

```
234 / 100 = 2 , 
234 % 10 = 4, 
4 % 10 = 4,
```

So totaling 10

Answer (score 1):

This is to make it more general (more than 1000)

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a number:");
int num = input.nextInt();
int sum = 0;
while (num>0) {
    sum += num % 10;
    num = num / 10;
}
System.out.println("sum="+sum);
```